# Is it safe to leave a SLA battery connected to 12v all the time for "trickle charging"?

Tags: battery-charging, 12v, ups

I am considering building a 12v DC UPS for network equipment, and found [this other question which contains a description of how one might build such a device](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/11274/12v-dc-ups-for-network-equipment). It suggests:

> A Buck DC/DC converter handling charging, but a simple LM317 could also be used, especially if the battery is stored at a fixed temperature, (look up "SLA charger lm317).

The suggestion that a buck converter alone could be used for this purpose makes it sound like the battery would always be connected to the power source.

- Will this damage the battery or create a safety hazard?
- How would you determine the output voltage to set on the buck converter?

Comment: trickle charge (if not temp compenstated) 13.5 is ok at room temp http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_the_lead_acid_battery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A trickle charge "float voltage" in the range 13.5 to 13.8V is safe (and even healthy) to be continuously applied to a typical 12V lead acid battery.

Anything below that range won't effectively keep it charged, and above that range may cause long-term degradation.

Make sure the buck converter has adequate filtering - you might consider an extra LC filter stage on its output - so that the battery doesn't see ripple or switching transients that exceed 13.8V.